galvanic corrosion between stainless steel flex supply line and brass fixture?
I have a vintage Crane sink faucet. I assume the body, including the connection points, of this is brass. Previously, it was attached using a rigid copper pipe. The fittings that were used in the old days are no longer obtainable, so the supply house convinced me to instead use standard braided stainless steel flex lines. After connecting everything successfully, I wondered if there would be any problem with galvanic corrosion with the stainless steel touching the brass.
Is there any concern of galvanic corrosion where the stainless steel flex line attaches to the brass faucet body?
(I assume it's common to connect a flex line to copper pipe, but I'd like to know if that's a problem too. I am mostly concerned with not damaging my vintage faucet.)

ground the line

The "stainless" part of the flex lines is the braided covering, not necessarily the nuts at the end which contact the faucet. The nuts may even be electrically isolated from the braiding, depending on the exact construction. And there are similar-looking flexible water connectors where the braiding is gray, but non-metallic, which work every bit as well. In any event, I've worked for decades with flexible connectors on brass faucets and never observed any notable corrosion at the interface.
